# Upload file that is in the cpan database

Tags: perl, cpan

I have a small module on CPAN - http://search.cpan.org/~bessarabv/.

I made a mistake and at first uploaded file SQL-Easy-0.04.tar.gz and only then SQL-Easy-0.03.tar.gz After that CPAN thought that the 0.03 is the latest version of the module.
To fix this problem I've requested the deletion of the 0.04.

0.04 was deleted and the 0.03 became the latest version. Now I'm uploading file SQL-Easy-0.04.tar.gz to cpan, but I get the error when I try to upload It:

```
Submitting query

Could not enter the URL into the database. Reason:

Duplicate entry 'B/BE/BESSARABV/SQL-Easy-0.04.tar.gz' for key 1

This indicates that you probably tried to upload a file that is
already in the database. You will most probably have to rename
your file and try again, because PAUSE doesn't let you upload
a file twice.
```

I'm not sure that this is a correct behavior: I've deleted the file, so the record in the database should also be deleted.

Is there any way of uploading file to cpan without renaming it?

Comment: There's nothing preventing you from releasing 0.05 to get around this.

Comment: People might have 0.04 installed already. Releasing a different 0.04 would prevent them getting the upgrade. Go to a new version number.

Answer (score 4):

Release version 0.05 - there is no harm in having multiple versions, or even skipping a version number if you need to (do keep a Changes file as part of your distributions and put in comments about what has changed, even if "0.05 released because of mistake in 0.04").

As pointed out in the comments, people might have 0.04 installed already (even if it was only uploaded an hour or so ago). Releasing a different 0.04 would prevent them getting the upgrade and also cause other problems with CPAN Testers etc which is why the system stops you uploading something of the same name.

The delete option is there so you can remove older versions, not so you can re-upload them.

Comment: I can't see a problem if somebody has already installed 0.04. I want to upload to cpan the exact 0.04 version that is was there before. The only mistake was the order in which I've uploaed files at first.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any way of uploading file to cpan without renaming it? Well, "PAUSE doesn't let you upload a file twice" would seem to say no.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about 0.04, just upload 0.05, no kittens or baby seals will die.