# The support of the CPAN

Tags: perl, cpan

There is a great thing in a Perl world: CPAN. http://www.cpan.org/

But I can't find any support forum or discussion board or any bugtracker for CPAN itself.

Is there any?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you looking for these?

Comment: Is a tangential of the earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565671/upload-file-that-is-in-the-cpan-database

Comment: CPAN isn't one thing. It's a huge collection of things. What are you having trouble doing?

Comment: brian, daxim is completely right. My problem is explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565671/upload-file-that-is-in-the-cpan-database The stackoverflow is a great place to ask questions and recieve answers, but I would prefer to ask this question in more context place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The backend, [PAUSE](https://pause.perl.org/), is maintained at https://github.com/andk/pause. The miscellaneous static files of CPAN are maintained at https://github.com/perlorg/cpanorg. Work on CPAN is coordinated through the [cpan-workers](http://lists.perl.org/list/cpan-workers.html) list.

When you have problems with CPAN or PAUSE, use the lists
[module-authors](http://lists.perl.org/list/module-authors.html) (community support) or [modules](http://lists.perl.org/list/modules.html) (PAUSE admins).

Comment: Thank you. This is the exact answer I wanted to get. Going to look to https://github.com/andk/pause and lurk the maillists.

Answer (score 10):

CPAN is generally accessed through a variety of means, the most common of which is the `CPAN.pm` module, which has a Request Tracker that can be used for bugs here: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=CPAN.

A website commonly used to search CPAN, http://search.cpan.org/, is a closed-source site which does not have any community bugtracker.  It does have a [feedback page](http://search.cpan.org/feedback) if you want to send comments or bug reports to its maintainer.

Another common website used to search CPAN is http://metacpan.org/, which has its own [github](https://github.com/CPAN-API/cpan-api/wiki/FAQ) entry for bug reports.

Comment: Thank you. I've used http://pause.perl.org/ to upload modules to cpan, so I think I need some support from this site.

Answer (score 2):

Every CPAN module has a bugtracker at http://rt.cpan.org/ (but it's worth checking the documentation for the module as not all authors want to use it).

There's a discussion forum for CPAN modules at http://cpanforum.com/ - but it's rather underused.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're after the PAUSE FAQ
http://pause.perl.org/pause/query?ACTION=pause_04about#upload

***Please**, make sure the filename you choose contains a **version number**.  For security reasons you will never be able to upload a file with identical name again....*